# Can a boolean be included in an "if" statement?

Tags: lua

I'm just starting out on learning Lua (for 4 days now) and when running this code, I get an error: `input:2: 'then' expected near '='`

Here's the code I am using:

```lua
local imagineVar = true
if imagineVar = true then
    print("LOL")
end
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

```lua
if imagineVar then
    print("LOL") 
end
```

in lua, anything in if statment will be true except `false` and `nil`

Answer (score 4):

The error you're getting is a **syntax error** because assignments (`var = something`) are statements rather than expressions in Lua - that means they don't evaluate to a value and thus can't be used in an `if`-condition (or anywhere else where an **expression** is expected).

As others have pointed out, you'd use the **operator `==`** for comparison. It is however more idiomatic to check for truthiness if your variable is a boolean: `if imagineVar then ... end`; the body of the `if` will run only if `imagineVar` is not `nil` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Compare needs double '='

```
local imagineVar = true
if imagineVar == true then
  print("LOL") 
end
```

Comment: This answer is a slightly incorrect, the variable being a boolean, the condition should be `if imagineVar then`. In this answer, the variable `imagineVar` will be evaluated to `true` or `false` in a first place, and then compared to `true` (i.e. `true == true` or `false == true`).

Comment: @Robert It's not "incorrect", just unnecessary; there's nothing wrong per se with comparing a boolean to `true` ;)

Comment: It's not unnecessary if you want to only accept a boolean true, in cases where imagineVar could be any data type. For whatever reason.